# State is wrongly updated in react app , object however shows correct values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have the following state in my React component:

```
state = {
        genderRadioClick : false,
        ageRadioClick : false
    }
```

I have the following function that gets called onChange of every radio button in the component:

```
_updateRadioButtonValuesObsolte = (e) => {

    let newStateOfCheckboxs = {
        genderRadioClick : Array.from(document.getElementsByName('customer_gender')).some( (elem , idx) => {  return elem.checked  }),
        ageRadioClick : Array.from(document.getElementsByName('customer_age')).some( (elem , idx) => {  return elem.checked  })
    }

    console.log(newStateOfCheckboxs);

    this.setState({
        ...newStateOfCheckboxs
    });

    console.log(this.state);

}
```

When i check one of the radio button and the following line of code runs:

```
console.log(newStateOfCheckboxs); // {genderRadioClick: true, ageRadioClick: false}
```

Which is correct , but the output of the below line:

```
console.log(this.state);  // {genderRadioClick: false, ageRadioClick: false}
```

is wrong , Why are the values of the keys in the compomemnt state wrong ? Even though i am updating as below:

```
this.setState({
            ...newStateOfCheckboxs
        });
```

What am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: `setState` is async; you're querying it before the state has been set.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setState is an asynchronous function

this.setState({
    ...newStateOfCheckboxs
});
console.log(this.state);

By this you are expecting state to be immediately updated after setState is called. But you can follow a callback approach

```
this.setState({
    ...newStateOfCheckboxs
}, function(){
console.log(this.state);
});
```